# best way to manage about 5 laravel website on vps?

Tags: laravel, web, hosting, vps, configure

i have a vps with 2Gb Ram and 1 Core cpu(2GHz), i can choose the OS, i chose ubuntu 16.04 and i could configure the LAMP and run one of my sites, but it was a little bit pain for me, i can install free Hosting CP on vps, but i dont think its neccessary for only few website.can any one give me clue how to manage them, consider that i havent enough knowledge in server configuratin and security of it.

Comment: "Manage" is quite a broad term, what would you be wanting to do exactly. Also is "CP" cPanel?

Comment: cp => hosting control panel (free ones)

Comment: by manage i mean be able to update,add,secure,backup ... common task with a website

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the knowledge, so, i recommend not to do it yourself in the first place. Setup is not the hardest part but think about security, backups, maintenance that is sometimes not that easy.

If you really want your own vps, i recommend to use something like https://forge.laravel.com or any other alternative. This handles a couple of things for you like security and setup.

Answer (score 0):

go with something that gives you full control and is opensource so you can find alot of support. I use Webmin+Virtualmin.

Comment: i install Virtualmin but where should i put laravel file in virtual host folder ?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply @Mostafa , what you can do with virtualmin is modify your virtual host folder structure in such a way that it corresponds with your laravel directory. This should give you a good idea. If you require step by step process, just let me know. I hope it helps.